# Using Redis to synchronize requests in Django

Tags: python, django, redis, gevent

I am trying to synchronize incoming connections using Redis `lpush/blpop`.

For example, one user attempts to load the page, and his connection blocks via `blpop`.
As soon as a second user starts loading the page they `lpush`, releasing the first connection.

Instead the first `blpop` seems to block the entire server and the second connection never enters the view.

Here is a minimal example of what I'm trying:

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import redis

r = redis.StrictRedis()

def two_view(request):
    print('Starting request')
    if r.get('waiting') == '1':
        print('Someone is waiting')
        r.set('waiting', 0)
        print('Pushing key')
        r.lpush('waiting_key', 1)
        return HttpResponse('Released lock, we both go')
    else:
        print('Nobody is waiting.')
        r.set('waiting', 1)
        print('Begin waiting for other')
        r.blpop('waiting_key')
        return HttpResponse('set waiting higher, to: {}'.format(r.get('waiting')))
```

manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "basic.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from views import two_view

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', two_view),
)
```

And the output when I point two tabs at it:

```
(env)Vincents-MacBook-Pro:basic vkhougaz$ python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
April 04, 2014 - 02:38:34
Django version 1.6.2, using settings 'basic.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Starting request
Nobody is waiting.
Begin waiting for other
```

And both tabs never finish loading.

Here is a working example of what I am trying to do:

```
import redis
from gevent import monkey
import gevent
monkey.patch_all(thread=False)
from time import sleep

conpol = redis.ConnectionPool()

def do_lock_thing_1():
    r = redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool=conpol)
    print('starting thing 1')
    r.blpop('k')
    print('finishing thing 1')

def do_lock_thing_2():
    r = redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool=conpol)

    print('starting thing 2')
    sleep(1)
    r.lpush('k', 1)
    print('finishing thing 2')

r2 = redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool=conpol)

r2.delete('k')

t1 = gevent.spawn(do_lock_thing_1)
t2 = gevent.spawn(do_lock_thing_2)

gevent.joinall([t1, t2])
```

And the output:

```
starting thing 1
starting thing 2
<1 second delay>
finishing thing 2
finishing thing 1
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was not with django or gevent or redis, rather chrome was queueing the connections. If I use two different browsers the code works as expected.

[Blocking calls with Gevent and WSGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098284/blocking-calls-with-gevent-and-wsgi)